# Runtime exec command working when when run from terminal but not eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tesseract, runtime.exec

I'm trying to use tesseract to do OCR on an image in java. I realize there are wrappers like Tess4J that provide a bunch more functionality and stuff, but I've been struggling to get it set up properly. Simply running a one-line command with Runtime is really all I need anyways since this is just a personal little project and doesn't need to work on other computers or anything.

I have this code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(scan("full-path-to-test-image"));
    }
    public static String scan(String imgPath) {
        String contents = "";
        String cmd = "[full-path-to-tesseract-binary] " + imgPath + " stdout";
        try { contents = execCmd(cmd); }
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        return contents;
    }
    public static String execCmd(String cmd) throws java.io.IOException {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd).getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }
}
```

When it's compiled and run directly from terminal, it works perfectly. When I open the exact same file in eclipse, however, it gives an IOException:

`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "tesseract": error=2, No such file or directory`

What's going on? Thank you for any help.

Comment: You will want to become familiar with the concept of “current directory” and “relative path.”  These are not Java concepts, but fundamental file system concepts.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're suggesting. Tesseract isn't in the current directory/working directory when the program's run directly from terminal or from eclipse, and the command works regardless of the current directory when on the command line.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the output.  I took it to mean that tesseract itself could not find your file.  But I may be wrong.  It may be that Eclipse is running in an environment with a different PATH environment variable than your terminal’s shell.

Comment: I changed the cmd string to include the full path to the binary, so the PATH variable shouldn't make a difference any more, correct?

Comment: You can try to print out the environment for both runs, from terminal and from IDE, and see if there's anything different there

Comment: Correct, that should fix it.

Comment: Okay, so I thought the full path to the binary still wasn't working and was very confused. Turns out eclipse made a copy of the test class when I opened it with the same name and the modified version to include the full path wasn't the one set to run in the run configuration. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the working folder in the run configuration for the Test class in Eclipse. I bet it's different from the one when you run the same program from a terminal.

Comment: I set them to be the same, but no luck. Tesseract was installed with homebrew, so it's not located in either of the directories the java files are in anyways.

Comment: So then in both cases the Tesseract binary is supposed to be located via the system PATH variable? As a wild guess - restart your IDE. If you installed Tesseract after starting your IDE, it won't receive any updates to the PATH that happened after it was started

Comment: Seems that wasn't the problem. Also, to eliminate possible problems coming from the PATH variable I replaced the cmd string with the full path to the binary.